# Trying to add time stamp but getting warnings

Tags: ios, directory, timestamp

I am trying to save a photo to a directory however to stop duplicating I am using timestamp so .However I am getting error that is saying unused variable timestamp. How can I clear this??

```
 NSString *timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%HatsImage",unixtime];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming unixtime is of type long, do the following:

```
NSString *timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ldHatsImage",unixtime];
```

Comment: THIs is the same thing that I did read  the question please or tell me where is different

Comment: No, there is a small, but important difference. It uses %d for formatting the integer. For a string you would use %@.

Comment: See the [String programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html) for further details.

Comment: I am getting more errors saying format specifies type int but the argument has type 'time_t'(aka long) and another warning noting that unused variable timestamp..

Comment: @user2404396 Use `%ld` since `unixtime` is a `long`. The warning about `timestamp` means that you are not using the `timestamp` variable.

Comment: How can I do that can you tell me in detail please

Comment: Just like @rmaddy said. I have updated the answer to include the 'long' version.

Comment: @user2404396 You clear the warning by using the variable in your code.